# urllib.urlretreive completely locks up Python?

Tags: python, windows-7, urllib

Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
urlretrieve('http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.12/chromedriver_win32.zip', 'chromedriver_win32.zip')
```

Whether I try to enter these directly into an interactive session of Python or save them into a script then try to execute the script, Python completely locks up and never recovers (I waited ten minutes for it). It won't even let me use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to quit Python - I have to close the terminal entirely.

If I include a report function, it shows that the entire file is quickly downloaded (~1 second) - but then it locks up, exactly as it does in the example I included above.

No exceptions are thrown by Python, so I'm not sure what to do about this.

If I check in the Windows File Explorer, it shows that the zip file is in the directory that I ran the code from, but it shows up as having the proper size and if I try to open it I get an error message

> Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped) Folder '[path omitted...]' is invalid.

If I enter the same URL into Chrome, it downloads the file in under a second, and Windows Explorer is able to open the zip file just fine.

I'm on Windows 7 running Python 2.7.8.

Comment: Working properly on OS X Yosemite with Python 2.7.6

Comment: @VinayJain - Thanks for letting me know that. Could you try using Python 2.7.8 and letting me know if that works (I'll try downgrading to 2.7.6 and seeing if that works for me). It can help determine if this is an OS specific issue or a version specific issue (or both).

Comment: I just went for updating Python in my Mac and look, its throwing errors :(

Comment: @VinayJain - Wait, so this is an error with all versions of Python 2.7.8? 2.7.9 is going into RC tomorrow with a planned release in a month. Should definitely try to get someone to address this now or else there won't be a fix for several months. Would you mind explaining what errors you got, exactly?

Comment: I upgraded to Python 2.7.8 and the code in your Question works fine on my Mac, there may be some problem in your Python installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be a bug in the Python standard library, I filed a bug report and looked for a work around. Here's what I decided to do:

1 - Install requests, using `pip install requests`.

2 - Use it in my code, like this:

```
from requests import get
from shutil   import copyfileobj

response = get('http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.12/chromedriver_win32.zip', stream=True)
with open('chromedriver_win32.zip', 'wb') as f:
    copyfileobj(response.raw, f)
```

Seems to work fine - Windows recognizes the downloaded file as a valid zip with a proper size and unzips it properly.